# Where Do We Report SharePoint Online Bugs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I just need to know the proper place to report SharePoint Online bugs to Microsoft.

I've found a couple:

One when setting up a Site Mailbox, after selecting Language and Time Zone, I get, "The custom error module does not recognize this error.".  (Might be because Outlook isn't set up yet, but I wish the error said that.)

The other is in the OOB Issue List. I tried changing Category from dropdown to checkboxes and the error is, "Non-supported field type change. The field cannot be changed to the new type. Please check the new type and try again.".

Answer (score 6):

You need to log into the O365 admin portal and go to Support -> Service Requests. There you can add requests.

https://portal.office.com/admin/default.aspx#ServiceRequestsPage

Comment: Then prepare for Microsoft's horrible support.  I had to submit a ticket once, and they came back asking me how the environment was set up (how many servers, etc).  Shouldn't they know that info?

Comment: Oh yeah no...I do not want to submit a service request. I've walked them through a bug, that they duplicated and they *still* came back (at least a week later) and asked me about my environment.

Comment: That's the only way I know to submit bugs or service issues, as terrible as the support is.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices with that.

- You can look in the bottom corner and click on feedback
- you can fill out a service request and put all of the information in
  it.
- You can call in for technical support and we can take all the
  information and screen shots that you have and put it in an
  appropriate bug report.
- Or if you have a TAM, or SSM then they can also submit the
  information for you.( this is if you have contract with the MSFT)

So if you write it up and attach screen shots in a word document, or OneNote document then it can be easily attached to a service request. and we can forward it to the appropriate team.http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/5452.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Support Request within your tenant, which is the obvious support channel, there are other places to go and find information on supposed bugs.

- The first place to look is of course here at SharePoint.StackExchange.com under the tags [office-365](/questions/tagged/office-365) and [sharepoint-online](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online) :-)
- Your second source of information is [the vivid community of Office 365](http://community.office365.com/) where users and admins posts various questions and get answers from other users and MS employees.

Often those thing we consider bugs, are actually restrictions to the cloud service in the Office 365 platform. Those type of “bugs” can be found here or at the Office 365 community.