# Copy Link button on default form does nothing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, hyperlink

I have created a list in a SPO site, and want to allow Contributors to add to it using a form. My organization has both PowerApps and InfoPath turned off and does not allow site owners to use any form of code, so I am not able to customize forms directly

After a great deal of fiddling to hide the Title column, I have the right columns displaying using the right controls when I click the "New" button in the list view. However, the "Copy link" button in the form pane copies nothing. I have tried in both Google Chrome (current) and Internet Explorer 11. Clicking the button causes angle brackets "<>" to appear superimposed on the screen in gray below the button, but no URL is copied.

[image]

I've also tried pasting into several applications in addition to the browsers in case it might be a content type issue - it is not.

So why would "Copy link" stop working?

Is there a known way to manually construct the URL when this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it does not work

`Copy link` is supposed to give you a link to an existing item. When you are trying to click this button from the context of the New form - the **item does not exist yet**. Hence - it is impossible to construct the link:

[image]

### Title field has nothing to do with this issue

I have replicated your case and I get the same <> wierd looking pop-up even with the untouched lists.

### How to get the URL to the new Form

You need the direct URL to the New form. This is how it looks like: `/Lists/<URL OF YOUR LIST>/NewForm.aspx`

For example, this is the url in my tenant: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Lists/CustomList/NewForm.aspx`

[image]

Comment: If the button never works: 1)Why did it work once? and 2)Why is it there?

Comment: 1) It could not have possibly worked for the *New* form. It works for Display only 2) the button is not supposed to be there. Modern UI has bugs like these that no one reported or found yet. You've just found the new bug. You can report it to Microsoft: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133828/where-do-we-report-sharepoint-online-bugs

Comment: Denis, it may be impossible that it worked, but then where did I get the link that I actually sent to people, and which actually works? I didn't know how to generate the form URL until you just told me (for which I thank you, by the way).

Comment: And having posted just a moment ago: now it works again. Some tiny change in SPO that MS made?

Comment: @CarlF, did you manage to make the "Copy link" button work on the New form? I think, what is probably hapening is that you are on the Display form, when you click on the existing item. In this case "Copy link" should work. Also, generating the link to the New form is easy: just add /NewForm.aspx right after the List's name in the URL. If you need help here - can you post an example URL of your list?

Comment: Sorry about not getting back, @Denis_Molodtsov. I've been off that project for a while. I'll remember the /NewForm.aspx trick for my next one.

Answer (score 0):

MS has "copy link" references all over sharepoint and O365 that do not "copy link". its pretty annoying. there are:

- "copy link" buttons that actually prompt user to use O365 to "send link" (very annoying difference)
- "copy link" buttons that spawn a window with the link available, so the user has to select it again and ctrl-C (very annoying)
  -"copy link" buttons that simply do nothing.

Is it possible MS is beginning to restrict users from copying SP URLs for some reason? it sure feels that way.

Comment: There is also the irritation that in SPO, "Copy link" will sometimes create a sharing link you didn't want and don't need--you just wanted a regular URL.